# Is it possible do define a global base path in hapi

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

I want every [hapi](https://hapijs.com) route path to start with a prefix (`/api/1`) without adding it to each route. Is this possible?

The following route should be available with path `/api/1/pets` and not `/pets`

```
const Hapi = require('hapi');
const server = new Hapi.Server();
server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/pets'
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best bet would be to use a constant in the paths -

```
server.route({
   method: 'GET',
   path: constants.route.prefix + '/pets')
});
```

and have the constant defined in a static constants.js file

Comment: It seems that this solution is the easiest and has leaset overhead. Because of that I will accept it but the other answers also provide possible solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Seems you can't do it globally for the whole application. But there's a possibility to add prefixes for all the routes defined inside a plugin:

```
server.register(require('a-plugin'), {
    routes: {
        prefix: '/api/1' 
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Just in case, if you're gonna try to add base path via events for new routes, it's not gonna work.

Comment: But that means I need to wrap my routes inside a plugin?

Comment: It does, but it wouldn't change a lot. Actually that's a way to modularize hapi apps which hapi encourages.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see such option in [Hapi docs](https://hapijs.com/tutorials/routing). Still, I can suggest you a small workaround. Make some function:

```
function createRoutePath(routePath) {
  return `/api/1${routePath}`;
}
```

And then use it this way:

```
server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: createRoutePath('/pets')
});
```

**UPDATE:**
As another workaround, leave all as is, and setup proxy web server. For example nginx.

Comment: If this is the only way it would be easier to just use a constant in path `path: prefix + '/pets'`.

Comment: Well, using nginx is not that bad. It's widely used in production, so no problem adding one more rule.